# Getting the values from a dictionary in python by passing a folder name as a key in a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am trying to iterate through the sub folders and get the associated value from a dictionary. The keys represent all the sub folder names exactly.My code is as below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import numpy as np
myDict = {}
myDict["Target-Turkish"] = "tr"
myDict["Target-Thai"] = "th"
myDict["Target-Swedish"] = "sv"
myDict["Target-Spanish"] = "es"
myDict["Target-Russian"] = "ru"
myDict["Target-Romanian"] = "ro"
myDict["Target-Portuguese(Brazil)"] = "pt"
myDict["Target-Polish"] = "pl"
myDict["Target-Norwegian(Bokmal)"] = "no"
myDict["Target-Malay(Malaysia)"] = "ms"
myDict["Target-Korean"] = "ko"
myDict["Target-Japanese"] = "ja"
myDict["Target-Italian"] = "it"
myDict["Target-Indonesian"] = "in"
myDict["Target-German"] = "de"
myDict["Target-French"] = "fr"
myDict["Target-Dutch"] = "nl"
myDict["Target-Danish"] = "da"
myDict["Target-Czech"] = "cs"
myDict["Target-Chinese(Taiwan)"] = "zh_TW"
myDict["Target-Chinese(PRC)"] = "zh_CN"
myDict["Target-Arabic(U.A.E.)"] = "ar"
file_name = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\anoop\\Data Upload Random Forms")
print(myDict.get(file_name[3]))
```

When I try to get the value by substituting the key with the folder name-

```
print(myDict.get(file_name[3]))
```

I am getting `None` as the output. But when I try

```
print(myDict.get('Target-French'))
```

(this is the exact folder name), i get the intended value which is `fr`. I am new to python. I would really appreciate if any one can shed some light into this

Comment: It's obviously not the exact folder name or it would work. Maybe there are spaces in the folder name, or different upper/lower case.

Comment: Show `print(repr(file_name[3]))`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar .  It was the space in the folder names in dictionary. When I corrected that, it worked like a charm . Thank you so much for the quick reply.